# puppet: ensure line in specific order

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet

i am newbie to puppet, have requirement to define new parameter to the attached code.
I want to have the option to add order line to the attached code.

can someone help me with some examples please ?

```
module Puppet
        newtype(:ensureline) do
                @doc = "ensureline doc"
                newparam(:name) do
                        desc "The name of the resource"
                end
                newparam(:file) do
                        desc "file to edit"
                end
                newparam(:line) do
                        desc "line to ensure"
                end
                newproperty(:ensure) do
                        desc 'Whether the line present or not?'
                        defaultto :present
                        def retrieve
                                File.readlines(resource[:file]).map {
                                        |line|
                                        line.chomp
                                }.include?(resource[:line]) ? :present : :absent
                        end
                        newvalue :absent do
                                # This block of code will make the :line absent in :file
                                data = File.readlines(resource[:file])
                                data.map! {
                                        |line|
                                        line.chomp
                                }.delete(resource[:line])
                                File.open(resource[:file], 'w') {
                                        |fd|
                                        fd.puts data
                                }
                        end
                        newvalue :present do
                                # This block of code will make the :line present in :file
                                File.open(resource[:file], 'a') {
                                        |fd|
                                        fd.puts resource[:line] + "\n"
                                }
                       end
                end
        end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Why use this when `file_line` from `stdlib` exists?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I'm going to check it :)

Comment: But if you do want to proceed with your own custom type, then you should consider reading [the documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/custom_types.html) about how to do that.